# Spring PropertiesFactoryBean wildcard expansion not working

Tags: java, spring, apache-karaf, spring-dm, spring-properties

I'm trying to use PropertiesFactoryBean to load all files ending with `.prop`from certain directory.

```
<bean id="props" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="location" value="file:/etc/app/*.prop"/>
</bean>
```

When running this as Junit test, everyting works OK and `org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport#loadProperties` get list of all files (wildcard expanded) as `FileSystemResource` 
and loads them.

However when running in OSGI environment (Karaf) `PropertiesLoaderSupport#loadProperties` will get single `OsgiBundleResource` with path set to `/etc/app/*.prop` which is invalid, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `locations` property instead of `location` (which supports only one resource)

```
<bean id="props" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="locations" value="file:/etc/app/*.prop"/>
</bean>
```